# Server side method in JavaScript method or at template Field

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to call server side method in JavaScript method or at template Field
trying below didt help much

```
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <ItemTemplate>
    <input type="button" value="sacfSD" id=<%# getCallJS('<%# Eval("FLD232") %>') %> />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

C# server side method

```
public void getCallJS(string ii)
{
     qyr.Value = enc.EncryptToString(ii);
}
```

Comment: Hi, you need to provide more information in your question. what are you trying to do? what errors did you get? what happened when you googled for the error message? Please *edit your question* and add all the relevant information or we can't help you.

Comment: i was trying to cal server side method in javascript
when i try above code it give me an error " Newline in constant"

Comment: Don't tell me (in the comments) this info is part of your complete question... edit your question and add the info there :) The more info you give, the better and more quickly you're likely to get help

Comment: You have another option to use `RowDataBound` event of `GridView`

Comment: Your server side method doesn't have return type. Exactly what your method is doing?

Comment: Use ajax that will help you to call server side code from javascript

Comment: What you need is generate ids on server side and bind it.

Comment: @amit can you explain little more

Comment: Please explain scenario of generating id from Javascript literal. How JavaScript got that literal value?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to [Implement Client Callbacks Programmatically Without Postbacks in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208(v=vs.100).aspx)